# docker for mac: access mongo from another container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have two container, one is a container for node.js code and another for a mongodb database.  I set the network_mode to host for both containers, there are certain network restrictions making me have to do this.  Additionally, both container are on the same physical mac machine.  If I want to connect to the mongodb database from the node.js container, what should my connection string look like.  I know that if I used a bridged network, I would use the name of the mongo container for the host name.  However, in this case I have tried localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, etc. none of which are working.  How would I access the mongdb database in this case?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to use docker inspect and find the IP of the docker container and login/connect to it. Alternatively you can use VS Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and install docker plugin

find running docker containers and container ids

```
docker ps
```

get details of the docker specific docker container

```
docker inspect <CONTAINER ID> | grep "IPAddress"
```

example

```
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

VS Code docker plugin 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3800#issuecomment-496480571), `network_mode` doesn't work on Docker for Mac.

The comment on the issue I linked *did* say that if you need to access a service on the host from a container, you can use `host.docker.internal`, but this might not be relevant to your use case.